# Nested block types in Episerver

Tags: episerver

I am about to build a block for creating content tables in Episerver.

I would like this block to have a `ContentArea` which in turn will contain only blocks of type `TableRowBlock` (so that I can have an arbitrary number of rows).

If I create a block type called `TableBlock` and another one called `TableRowBlock`, they will both be visible when an editor adds a new block.

Since `TableRowBlock` only makes sense within a `TableBlock`, I would like to hide it so that it is only visible when adding a block to the `ContentArea` property of a `TableBlock`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking isn't supported out-of-the-box, I'm afraid.

However, you could:

1. Add an `[AllowedContentTypes]` attribute to your `ContentArea` property for `TableBlock`, and specify the `TableRowBlock` type as the allowed type. That way the editor won't have to select block type when clicking "Add new block" in the content area editor.
2. Customize which content type(s) are suggested when new content is created by creating your own `IContentTypeAdvisor` which would suggest `TableRowBlock` when `TableBlock` is being edited:

`[ServiceConfiguration(typeof(IContentTypeAdvisor))]
        public class ContentTypeAdvisor : IContentTypeAdvisor
        {
            public IEnumerable<int> GetSuggestions(IContent parent, bool contentFolder, IEnumerable<string> requestedTypes)
            {
                // Suggest relevant content types
            }
        }`

Full example [available here](https://talk.alfnilsson.se/2016/04/17/customize-suggested-pageblock-types-when-creating-content/).

Comment: I see! Do you know if there is any other preffered way of doing a list with dynamic length, other than use the contentarea type?

Comment: You can have a look at the PropertyList API. It's still in beta, but I think it works fairly well: http://world.episerver.com/blogs/Per-Magne-Skuseth/Dates/2015/11/trying-out-propertylistt/